# Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus

Tags: windows-7, openssl, symfony-3.3

**I remain like this as screenshot without answer (to give the password) what is the problem according to your experiences**.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @helen, same happens on Linux with openssl 1.0.1. I don't see any issue here as long as openssl generates correct key.